# Getting error that "LinearLayout does not contains anychild named com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to Create common G+ sign up button in C#,Xamarin, But I am Getting error that "LinearLayout does not contains any child named com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton"

I have installed Google Play Services too in android sdk and added component in Visual studio also. 
But I am not sure which google play services should I add in visual studio.
Please suggest asap.

Please find screen shot-

[image]

Comment: Could you post the full error message? It's not clear in the screenshot

Comment: @Prashant,here is full error msg...Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  The element 'LinearLayout' has invalid child element 'com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton'. List of possible elements expected: 'GLSurfaceView, AdapterView, AdapterViewAnimator, AutoCompleteTextView, MediaController, TextView, FragmentBreadCrumbs, AppWidgetHostView, GestureOverlayView, ExtractEditText, KeyboardView, RSSurfaceView, RSTextureView, SurfaceView,

Answer (score 0):

You need to add nuget package of [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Plus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Plus/). This will install the following references.

- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Plus

Then you can use Sign In button in layout via

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

> **Note :** Even though layout designer shows the warning, the app will run without any issues.

Comment: yes @sJy, I have added nuget package xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Plus  and also have 3 references u specified.still getting that error.

Comment: @DhanshreeMore Even though the layout designer shows that warning, it will run in the device with the button getting displayed properly.

Comment: @DhanshreeMore Pleae mark the status so that it will be useful for other users to check unanswered questions.